# Android Mediaplayer UnixSocket FileDescriptor avc: denied { read write }

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-bluetooth, unix-socket

I'm trying to stream video via Bluetooth to my Android 6 Nexus 5 device. Since I'm unable to obtain the FileDescriptor from the BluetoothSocket to feed it to the android MediaPlayer I created proxy using LocalSocket like this:

```
public class VideoProxy extends Thread {

private static final String TAG = "VideoProxy";
public static String SOCKET_ADDRESS = "bluetooth2localsocketproxy";

private LocalServerSocket mLocalServerSocket;
private LocalSocket mLocalSocket;
private OutputStream mLocalOutputStream;

private BluetoothSocket mRemoteServerConnection;
private InputStream mBluetoothSocketInputStream;
private static final byte BUFFER[] = new byte[4096];

public VideoProxy(BluetoothSocket remoteServerConnection) throws IOException {
    mRemoteServerConnection = remoteServerConnection;
    mLocalServerSocket = new LocalServerSocket(SOCKET_ADDRESS);
}

private boolean softStopped() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        mLocalSocket = mLocalServerSocket.accept();
        mLocalOutputStream = mLocalSocket.getOutputStream();
        Log.d(TAG, "run: accepted local conn");
        mRemoteServerConnection.connect();
        mBluetoothSocketInputStream = mRemoteServerConnection.getInputStream();
        Log.d(TAG, "run: connected to remote server");

        while(!softStopped()) {
            int read = 0;
            while((read = mBluetoothSocketInputStream.read(BUFFER)) > 0) {
                if(softStopped()) {
                    mRemoteServerConnection.close();
                    mLocalSocket.close();
                    break;
                }
                mLocalOutputStream.write(BUFFER, 0, read);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "run: ", e);
    }
}}
```

When I try to setDataSource to the android player:

```
try {
        Log.d("Paired with", mDevice.getName());
        mSocket = mDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(new UUID(0x0000000000000000L, 0x000000000000abcdL));
        videoReverseProxy = new VideoProxy(mSocket);
        videoReverseProxy.start();
        mUnixDomainSocket = new LocalSocket();
        mUnixDomainSocket.connect(new LocalSocketAddress(videoReverseProxy.SOCKET_ADDRESS));

        Log.d(TAG, "connectToRDServer: Connected");

        if(mUnixDomainSocket.getFileDescriptor() != null && mUnixDomainSocket.getFileDescriptor().valid()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToRDServer: FileDescriptor: " + mUnixDomainSocket.getFileDescriptor());
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mRemoteView.getHolder());
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mUnixDomainSocket.getFileDescriptor());
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Blueberry Remote", "onOptionsItemSelected: Unable to connect to remote server", e);
        notifyConnectionEstablishmentFailed();
        return;
    }
```

I get the following errors:

> type=1400 audit(0.0:90): avc: denied { read write } for
>   path="socket:[73452]" dev="sockfs" ino=73452
>   scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768
>   tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0 02-07 10:20:23.927
>   19902-19902/com.freeware.nikola.blueraspberrycontrol
>   E/Blueberry Remote: onOptionsItemSelected: Unable to connect to remote
>   server
>                                                                                               java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x80000000
>                                                                                                   at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
>                                                                                                   at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1158)
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.freeware.nikola.blueraspberrycontrol.BlueberryRemote.connectToRDServer(BlueberryRemote.java:158)
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.freeware.nikola.blueraspberrycontrol.BlueberryRemote.onOptionsItemSelected(BlueberryRemote.java:114)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2914)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:361)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:147)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:68)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:172)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:760)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 02-07
>   10:20:23.927 19902-19902/com.freeware.nikola.blueraspberrycontrol
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 02-07 10:20:23.928
>   19902-19902/com.freeware.nikola.blueraspberrycontrol E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                             Process: com.freeware.nikola.blueraspberrycontrol, PID: 19902
>                                                                                             java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.freeware.nikola.blueraspberrycontrol.BlueberryRemote.notifyConnectionEstablishmentFailed(BlueberryRemote.java:183)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.freeware.nikola.blueraspberrycontrol.BlueberryRemote.connectToRDServer(BlueberryRemote.java:163)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.freeware.nikola.blueraspberrycontrol.BlueberryRemote.onOptionsItemSelected(BlueberryRemote.java:114)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2914)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:361)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:147)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:68)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:172)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:760)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

The stream is encoded in h264 with ffmpeg and fed from my local machine.
Any ideas what the issue may be ? Thank you

Comment: The selinux policy on your phone prevents avc from writing to unix sockets. I don't know how to fix this without root though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806516/avc-denied-connectto-when-using-uds-on-android-10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [avc: denied { connectto } when using uds on Android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806516/avc-denied-connectto-when-using-uds-on-android-10)