# avc: denied { connectto } when using uds on Android 10

Tags: android

I'm running 2 applications on Android 10 device which communicate each other via uds. Everything worked fine until I changed the apps settings to target android 10. I get following error in logcat:

```
09-07 13:33:18.136 14573 14573 W <myapp_name>: type=1400 audit(0.0:1461891): avc: denied { connectto } for pid=14573 comm=474C546872656164203134353530 path=005368617265644D656D6F727953657276696365 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
```

After some digging I found neverallow SELinux policy:

```
neverallow { all_untrusted_apps -mediaprovider } init:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

Is there a way I can make it work on applications targeting Android 10?

Answer (score 2):

UDS with abstract path doesn't work for API>=28 due to the following changes.

> Per-app SELinux domains
> Apps that target Android 9 or higher cannot share data with other apps using world-accessible Unix permissions. This change improves the integrity of the Android Application Sandbox, particularly the requirement that an app's private data is accessible only by that app.
>
> To share files with other apps, use a content provider.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#framework-security-changes